# Why trigger function is not working?

Tags: jquery

My code is

Save

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 jQuery('#step2continue').click(function(){
         jQuery('#quizresultsave').trigger('click');

  });
```

When click on the save link,the follwing function should trigger,but this not working in iphone - safari.

```
     jQuery("#global_page_user-signup-quizresults").on(handleClick,'#quizresultsave',function(){
     jQuery("#global_page_user-signup-quizresults").empty();
     jQuery("#global_page_user-signup-quizresults").addClass('taskloading');

     jQuery("#global_page_user-signup-quizresults").html('<div class="spinnerlogo"></div>');

     jQuery(".container").removeClass('quizresult');

          var sSaveUrl = en4.core.staticBaseUrl + 'user/signup/introcomplete/';
          var oRpost = new Object();
          oRpost.user = '<?php echo $this->userId; ?>';
          jQuery.ajax({
                  url:sSaveUrl,
                  type: "POST",
                  data:oRpost,
                  success:function(data) {
                    if(data === 'success'){
                        //var url = en4.core.staticBaseUrl + 'members/home/firstland';
                         var url = en4.core.staticBaseUrl + 'share_on_socialmedia';
                        jQuery(location).attr('href',url);
                    } else {
                       <?php if($this->level == 7 ){  ?>
                        loadstep('6','3');
                       <?php } else {?>
                        loadstep('7','3');
                        <?php } ?>
                    }
                  }
               });

});
```

this trigger function is not working in safari-ipad

Comment: `$('#step2continue').click(function({$('#quizresultsave').trigger('click');});` should work. But what do you want to do?

Comment: Any errors in the console? Is `quizresultsave` an `<a>` element? If so use `jQuery('#quizresultsave')[0].click()`

Comment: What version of jQuery you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that you are looking for?

```
    <script>
      $(document).on("click", "#quizresultsave", function(){
        $(this).text("Clicked");
      });

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#step2continue').click(function(){
            $("#quizresultsave").trigger("click");
            });
        });
  </script>
  <div id="step2continue" onclick="">test tes tes test </div>
  <div id="quizresultsave" onclick="alert('tt')">testingggggg</div>
```